# ng-table fixed header and scroll bar

Tags: css, angular, ngtable

I am using this [NG-TABLE](http://valor-software.com/ng2-table/) and having a hard time trying to modify CSS. I want fixed header and scroll bar for the data. I am using CSS [in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23712497/angularjs-ng-table-fixed-headers).

My html looks like this.

```
<ng-table class="table-scroll" [config]="config"
          [rows]="rows" [columns]="columns">
</ng-table>
```

I opened developer tools and observed that table scroll css is not working.

I found the issue. User agent css is overwriting my css. Inside ng-table, there is another table and clss. How can I override that ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the standard `class` attribute its value can be ignored by the Angular element.

Much better to go with [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) instead, as it will append its values to any classes added by the element:

```
<ng-table [ngClass]="'table-scroll'" [config]="config" [rows]="rows" [columns]="columns">
</ng-table>
```

Example plunker:  https://plnkr.co/edit/d4uFrAsnRJqYMqiyLuTG?p=preview

A second option would be to change the selector from `.table-scroll thead ...` to the generic table selector `table thead ... etc`, if you don't have other tables on the page that would be affected.

Comment: @scandrett. I tried both options you gave me. It is not working

Comment: @Chatra Works with `[ngClass]` when I tried it - https://plnkr.co/edit/d4uFrAsnRJqYMqiyLuTG?p=preview

Comment: @scandrett. I tried again. Your plunker looking good but as I said in my question table style is  overwritten by ng-table class. You can see that in my chrome developer tools screenshot

Comment: The `<table class="table dataTable...">` is what is generated by the `<ng-table>` element, not the 'user agent'. It is never going to include `table-scroll` class in there because that isn't specified in the Ng2Table component's code, but nor does it need to. If you use `ngClass` instead of `class` it adds the class to `<ng-table>` tag that encloses `<table>`. The CSS selector ".table-scroll thead" says apply to any `<thead>` at any depth within a parent element with the `table-scroll` class. So the class doesn't need to be applied to the `<table>` directly to work (as shown in the fiddle)

Comment: Updated plunker with more of NgTable's styling https://plnkr.co/edit/gj5Y0UP3KQDdYsXspwYZ?p=preview. The scrolling still works correctly. If you look in Dev Tools, you'll see `table-scroll` class applied to `<ng-table>`. If you want to override the CSS used by Ng2Table just include your css after their stylesheets, copy and use their selectors with your custom values.

Answer (score 0):

As the structure is bit different, you can adjust your CSS:

```
.table-scroll table thead {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.table-scroll table tbody {
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.table-scroll table tr {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.table-scroll table td {
    height: 47px; // needed in order to keep rows from collapsing
}
```

Eventually you can add `!important` to the rules that can't be overwritten...

Comment: will try and let you know. Thank you!

Comment: Nope, it is not working. Style is overwritten by ng-table which I showed in chrome developer tools screenshot